# Scalar field equation of motion in FRW metric

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, field-theory, variational-principle

Consider a scalar field $\phi$ with the following Lagrangian density:

$$\mathscr{L}=-\frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi-V(\phi),$$
and consider a FRW metric, whose line element is given by
$$\mathrm{d} s^{2}=-\mathrm{d} t^{2}+a(t)^{2}\left[\frac{\mathrm{d} r^{2}}{1-k r^{2}} + r^{2} \mathrm{d}\theta^{2} + r^{2} \sin^{2} \theta \mathrm{d}\phi^{2}\right],$$
with $a(t)$ being the FRW scale factor. According to e.g. [Turner 1983](https://inspirehep.net/literature/190271), the equation for motion for $\phi$ in this setting turns out to be
$$\ddot{\phi}+3 H \dot{\phi}+V^{\prime}(\phi)=0.$$

How do I derive this? I have varied the action of the scalar field and obtained the scalar field equation of motion for a generic metric $g_{\mu\nu}$:
$$g_{\mu\nu} \partial^\mu \partial^\nu \phi - \frac{\delta V(\phi)}{\delta \phi}=0.$$
Now, I suppose that the $\ddot{\phi}$ term in the equation of motion is sourced by the $g_{00}$ component of the metric tensor, but what is the origin of the term $3 H \dot{\phi}$ given the metric I have written above?

Comment: Are you sure the $g_{\mu\nu} \partial^\mu \partial^\nu \phi$ term shouldn't read $g_{\mu\nu} \nabla^\mu \nabla^\nu \phi$?

Comment: @scaphys I have varied the action with respect to the field, hence the term depending on $\delta \sqrt{-g} / \delta \phi$ should be null

Comment: @NíckolasAlves I thought covariant derivatives of a scalar coincided with its gradients

Comment: @gangio not the double covariant derivative: $\nabla \partial \neq \partial \partial$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake when you varied the action. Explicitly, the Lagrangian density is:
$$
\mathcal L = (-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi-V(\phi))\sqrt{-g}
$$
so the Euler-Lagrange equations actually give you:
$$
-\partial_\mu (\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\phi)+\sqrt{-g}V'(\phi) = 0
$$
which you usually rearrange as:
$$
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\mu (\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\phi)+V'(\phi) = 0
$$
and you recognize in the first term the Laplace-Beltrami operator, which is a covariant quantity that you can rewrite covariantly as $\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu\phi$.

The author was considering spatially homogeneous solutions, ie $\phi(t)$, so calculating:
$$
g = -a^6\frac{r^4\sin^2\theta}{1-kr^2}
$$
the equation simplifies to:
$$
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{d}{dt} (-\sqrt{-g}\dot\phi)+V'(\phi) = 0 \\
\ddot\phi+3\frac{\dot a}{a}\phi+V'(\phi) = 0 \\
$$
and if you set the Hubble constant to $H = \frac{\dot a}{a}$, you obtain the advertised equation (you'll notice that the factor $3$ comes from the $3$ spatial dimensions).

Hope this helps and tell me if something is not clear.

Comment: That was super helpful, thank you! Only thing I am struggling with is how to vary the lagrangian by $\delta \partial_\mu \phi$. E.g. is it right if I say  $\frac{\delta \mathrm{L}}{\delta \partial_\mu \phi} = -\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\frac{\delta \partial_\mu \phi}{\delta \partial_\mu \phi}\partial_\nu \phi -\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu \phi \frac{\delta \partial_\nu \phi}{\delta \partial_\mu \phi} = -\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu \phi  - \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu \phi \delta_\mu^\nu$?

Comment: No problem! You got the idea but the formalism is a bit off. Remember, the repeated indices in the Einstein convention are bound. You’d rather get: $$\frac{\delta L}{\delta \partial_\sigma\phi} = -\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}(\delta^\sigma_\mu\partial_\nu\phi+ \delta^\sigma_\nu\partial_\mu\phi)$$ using $$\frac{\delta \partial_\alpha\phi }{\delta \partial_\beta\phi}=\delta^\beta_\alpha$$

Comment: You are right of course, many thanks for your time :)

Comment: sorry to bother you, but I have further (very basic) doubts. The term $V'(\phi)$ appearing in the Euler-Lagrange equation is sourced by the term $\frac{\delta \mathrm{L}}{\delta \phi}$ right? If this is true, does this imply that $\frac{\delta \partial_\nu \phi}{\delta \phi}=0$? Thank you

Comment: $\mathcal L$ is a function of $\phi, \partial_\mu\phi$, so they are treated as independent variables (coordinates of the tangent bundle). Therefore, you have $\frac{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)}{\partial \phi} = 0$ as well as $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial (\partial_\mu\phi)} = 0$. Remember that partial derivatives mean you are keeping other variables constant, most subtleties involve in defining precisely which other variables are you keeping constant.

Comment: Final note, the operator $\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi}$ rigourously acts on the action, not $\mathcal L$, even in my own comment, replace $\delta$ by $\partial$.

Answer (score 0):

You do not obtain the $\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$ term probably because you have not used covariant derivative. I did the same mistake once...

The field is a scalar so when acting on the field, the covariant derivative reduces to the standard partial one. But the derivatives of the scalar field are the component of a vector field.
Thus, to compute the second order derivatives you must use the covariant one. The equation of motion is then
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\mu}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\phi)}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}.
\end{equation}

The covariant derivative act on the component of the $v=v^{\nu}\boldsymbol{e}_{\nu}$ where $\boldsymbol{e}_{\nu}$ is a basis vector, as:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\mu}v^{\nu}=\partial_{\mu}v^{\nu}+v^{\alpha}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\alpha}.
\end{equation}
If you apply this to the case in which $v^{\nu}=\partial^{\nu}\phi$ and substitute the christoffel symbols for the FLRW metric, you will obtain the correct equation of motion.

I should mention that there is an abuse of notation. The covariant derivative acts on vector not on components. What i have written is the $\nu$ component of the covariant derivative of the $v$ vector, which is usually indicated as $v^{\nu}_{;\mu}$ instead of $\nabla_{\mu}v^{\nu}$. Written out explicitly is $\nabla_{\mu}v=v^{\nu}_{;\mu}\boldsymbol{e}_{\nu}$.

Hope this helps.