# The equation of motion for the scalar field

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, space-expansion

Consider a scalar field ϕ with the following Lagrangian density in the FRW scale factor:

$L= (-\frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi -V(\phi)) \sqrt{-g}$,

the motion for ϕ in this setting turns out to be

$\ddot{\phi}+3H\dot{\phi}+{V}^\prime(\phi)=0$.

What is the origin of the term $3H\dot{\phi}$given the metric? I'm sorry, but I'm having trouble understanding. Could you please provide me with more details about that?

Comment: related: [Scalar field equation of motion in FRW metric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/713573/scalar-field-equation-of-motion-in-frw-metric/713589#713589)